# Integration of WebRTC with Liferay 6.2

Tags: video, liferay-6, webrtc

I have to integrate webrtc to liferay portal. I am unable to install or configure webrtc in my system may be the OS Linux or windows if any one known to the process of configuring or installing webrtc in any OS then please help me.
 I am using Liferay 6.2. WebRtc is a tool for video conference and I tried to configure a lot but dependency problem in ubuntu and for windows not getting useful resource.

Thanks

asif aftab

Answer (score 0):

WebRTC is a Javascript API for web browsers, integration with any web application should be independant of the OS.

There is a Liferay Marketplace portlet which has accomplished to integrate WebRTC with Liferay 6.1 [VideoChat WebRTC](http://www.liferay.com/es/marketplace?p_p_id=7_WAR_osbportlet&p_p_lifecycle=0&p_p_col_id=column-2&p_p_col_count=1&_7_WAR_osbportlet_mvcPath=/marketplace/view_app_entry.jsp&_7_WAR_osbportlet_backURL=/es/marketplace/-/mp/category/11232559&_7_WAR_osbportlet_appEntryId=35157703)

Also the place to start understanding and implementing your own webrtc application which deserves a look is http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/basics/

The most difficult and also free part of the webrtc implementation is the signaling phase where you should find a way (usually sockets) to send the config information from each peer to the other. The portlet referred early has done it without the need of a signaling server by using Liferay's Poller to exchange and deliver the messages.

Answer (score 0):

You can check TogetherJS: https://togetherjs.com/

It should be very easy to integrate it with Liferay and it provides basic conferencing functionalities (audio & chat).